# Trying to understand LSTM and varying lengths of input

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm

I'm trying to understand how LSTM networks work: I made a simple one based roughly on https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/
but detecting positive or negative use of word. So with bad.txt:

```
yuck
bad
no
bleh
never
hate
awful
```

and good.txt:

```
yum
good
yes
hooray
great
love
```

Now I can get a fairly "accurate" positive/negative detector at least for this small subset (overfitting, I know...). When I enter "great" it says positive, "awful" it says negative.

However, when I enter "reat" it say that is 99% negative, and "wful" is 99% positive. As I understand each "second letter" neuron would be looking for a second letter of something trained on and that may be the reason. Also, could it be because the blanks are used for padding any shorter words, and is there a more proper way to do this? That is to say, is there a more proper way to detect things of varying lengths, say words or audio snippets? I understand LSTM can be used with sequential/streaming data like characters coming from a streaming file of text, if this were being fed to an algorithm like this the "awful" would be counteracted by the bogus "wful"... is there a good way to correct this?

```
# Load LSTM network and generate text
import sys
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils import np_utils
import time

# create mapping of unique chars to integers, and a reverse mapping
chars = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
char_to_int = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
int_to_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
## summarize the loaded data
#n_chars = len(raw_text)
n_vocab = len(chars)
#print ("Total Characters: "+ str(n_chars))
#print ("Total Vocab: "+ str(n_vocab))
## prepare the dataset of input to output pairs encoded as integers
#seq_length = 100
dataX = []
dataY = []
seq_length = 7
for i in range(1000):
    with open('bad.txt') as bad:
        for line in bad:
            print(line+' mapping to [1,0]')
            nums = [char_to_int[n] for n in line.lower() if n in chars]
            while len(nums) < seq_length:
                nums.append(0)# " "
            dataX.append(nums)
            dataY.append([1,0])
    with open('good.txt') as bad:
        for line in bad:
            print(line+' mapping to [0,1]')
            nums = [char_to_int[n] for n in line.lower() if n in chars]
            while len(nums) < seq_length:
                nums.append(0)# " "
            dataX.append(nums)
            dataY.append([0,1])

n_patterns = len(dataX)
print ("Total Patterns: "+ str(n_patterns))

X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))
# normalize
X = X / float(n_vocab)
print(X[0:10])
# one hot encode the output variable
y = numpy.array(dataY)#np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)
# define the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
#model.add(Dropout(0.01))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
#This was step1.
filepath="simpleweights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
model.fit(X, y, epochs=20, batch_size=128, callbacks=callbacks_list)

# pick a random seed
start = numpy.random.randint(0, len(dataX)-1)
pattern = dataX[start]
print ("Seed:")
print ("\"", ''.join([int_to_char[value] for value in pattern]), "\"")
# generate characters
while True:
    word = input('word: ')
    numberize = []
    for l in word:
        if l in char_to_int:
            numberize.append(char_to_int[l])
    while len(numberize) < seq_length:
        numberize.append(0) #this space, first
    print(numberize)
    numberize = numpy.reshape(numberize, (1, len(numberize), 1))
    numberize = numberize / float(n_vocab) #normalize!
    print(numberize)
    result = (model.predict(numberize,verbose=0))
    print(result)
    #Just one. could do many at a time.
    if result[0][1] > result[0][0]:
        print('positive')
    else:
        print('negative')
```

Comment: You should probably train with data augmentation where you create examples from the original ones but missing one or two chars.

Comment: That makes sense, if it's to detect even with typos it would make sense to use some character replacements rather than repeating those on the input. It seems "hbte" or "yfs" or anywords with character just ahead of the one in the word, had minimal difference which doesn't make sense so much. Is there a setting where the numbers are categorical rather than a being next to b in value I wonder?

Comment: Ah, you should certainly try using an `Embedding` layer. Each character should be unique and independent. You still use sequential numbers in your input, but the embedding layer will choose a group of weights for each of these numbers.